# Return a List Based on Multiple Filters from Multiple Dataframes

Tags: python, list, dataframe, filter

How do I return a list based on multiple filters from multiple dataframes? I have three dataframes:

`df1`

```
    Ticker  Company Name    COMBOACCRUAL
0   ABC ABC Co. 0.9
1   DEF DEF Co. 0.99
2   GHI GHI Co. 0.5
```

`df2`

```
    Ticker  Company Name    PMAN
0   ABC ABC Co. 0.7
1   DEF DEF Co. 0.3
2   GHI GHI Co. 0.55
```

`df3`

```
    Ticker  Company Name    PFD
0   ABC ABC Co. 0.25
1   DEF DEF Co. 0.35
2   GHI GHI Co. 0.9
```

and I want to apply filters `COMBOACCRUAL<0.95`, `PMAN<0.95` and `PFD<0.95` on the dataframes `df1` `df2` and `df3` respectively so I could work further on the culled data.

The expected result should look like this:

`df4`

```
    Ticker  Company Name    COMBOACCRUAL    PMAN    PFD
0   ABC ABC Co. 0.9 0.7 0.25
2   GHI GHI Co. 0.5 0.55    0.9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Merge the three df together first and apply your filter?

```
columns = ['Ticker', 'Company', 'Name']

df4 = df1.merge(df2, on=columns).merge(df3, on=columns)

df4 = df4[(df4['COMBOACCRUAL'] < 0.95) & (df4['PMAN'] < 0.95) & (df4['PFD'] < 0.95)]
```

Comment: Thanks! I did a slight modification to your suggestion as my actual dataframes `df1`,`df2`, and `df3` contained more columns, `NaN` and `inf` than the example in my question above.

`columns = ['Ticker',  'Company Name']

df4 = df1[['Ticker',  'Company Name', 'COMBOACCRUAL']]. merge(df2[['Ticker', 'Company Name', 'PMAN']], on = columns). merge(df3[['Ticker', 'Company Name', 'PFD']], on = columns)

df4 = df4[(df4['COMBOACCRUAL'] < 0.95) & (df4['PMAN'] < 0.95) & (df4['PFD'] < 0.95)]

df4 = df4.dropna(axis = 0)

df4`